# Can't install Windows store app package (0x80070005)

Tags: installation, permissions, file-permissions, microsoft-store, installation-package

I tried to install (Ubuntu app) using windows store
it starts fine for a few seconds then it stops and gives me an error

> 0x80070005

Then I tried to download the package using *store.rg-adguard.net*
I get the same error as well

```
PS G:\ubuntu win> Add-AppxPackage

cmdlet Add-AppxPackage at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters: 
Path: G:\ubuntu win\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2020.418.0_neutral_~_79rhkp1fndgsc.AppxBundle 

Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT 0x80070005, Access is denied.
Unspecified error
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] f1ff6195-7b6c-0003-188c-fff16c7bd701 in the Event Log or use
the command line Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID f1ff6195-7b6c-0003-188c-fff16c7bd701
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AppxPackage
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo : SecurityError: (G:\ubuntu win\C...dgsc.AppxBundle:String) [Add-AppxPackage], PSSecurityE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
```

I opened PowerShell as admin. The user is also admin.
I also opened the Administrator account. I also have full control over the directory the package in and the place it should be installing (/program files/windows apps). I even changed the installation directory using regedit to (/program files/microsoft-store) which is a new directory I created and of course I have full access. But nothing works.

**How do I install the package??**

Comment: Did you enable WSL in Programs and Features, Windows Features?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @John, I did enable it. I'm trying to get the linux shell to run the dd command to make a uefi live usb of linux. I tried with Rufus but it only shows in legacy and no uefi option in boot sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I updated windows and the issue was resolved.